# How 400 BAD_REQUEST java api Put with exchangeToMono?

Tags: java

I have a java application that calls another application it works well for the exist get function my generate this error 400 BAD_REQUEST when I try to create with a Put function.

```
curl -XPUT URLSERVER2/users/usernameToBeUsed \
  -d '{"password":"passwordToBeUsed"}' \ 
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

```java
@Service
public class Server2Api {

    @Value("${source.server2.base.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private static final Duration REQUEST_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofSeconds(1);

    private final WebClient localApiClient;

    public Server2Api(WebClient.Builder localApiClient) {
        this.localApiClient = localApiClient.baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
    }


    public ResponseEntity<Void> creatUser(String username, String pwd){
        String body = "{'password':'"+ pwd +"'}";
        return localApiClient
                .put()
                .uri(baseUrl+"/users/"+username )
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(body)
                .exchangeToMono(
                        response -> response.toBodilessEntity()
                )
                .block(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    }

}
```

I just try to change "{'password':'"+ pwd +"'}" to "{password:'"+ pwd +"'}".

with Postman resquest works. URL is ok work on get function

Comment: Try `String body = "{\"password\":\""+ pwd +"\"}";`

Comment: thx it's that ^_^